# How to go through a number (float) and get every number separately with an int. Java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

Is there any good way to search through a floats first four numbers and return every number separately with int[]?

Example: the float 23,51 becomes the integer array, array[0]=2, array[1]=3, array[2]=5 and last array[3]=1

My code:

```
public void printNumber(float number){
    String string = String.valueOf(number);
    while(!numbers.isEmpty()){
        numbers.remove(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        int j = Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 10);
        this.number = new Number(j);
        numbers.add(this.number);
        System.out.println("digit: " + j);
    }
}
```

I should mention that Number is a class that only returns a different picture based on the number the constructor is given and ofcourse the number itself.

numbers is an ArrayList

Comment: "The first four numbers of a float" isn't well-defined for binary.

Comment: Does it mean that it can't be done?

Comment: convert to a string with a format specifier, then iterate through the string elements?

Comment: I have tried that without any luck, may be wrong somewhere in my code so I'll post it above.

Comment: What is the decimal precision for your float number?

Comment: Just the first four.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `float` to `String` using fixed-point format, then go through its characters one-by-one, and ignore the decimal point.

If the number could also be negative, you need to pay attention to the sign in the `String` output:

```
float v = 23.51F;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
char[] d = df.format(v).toCharArray();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != d.length ; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(d[i])) {
        count++;
    }
}
int[] res = new int[count];
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != d.length ; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(d[i])) {
        res[pos++] = Character.digit(d[i], 10);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/tv3xcA)

**Important:** Be aware that `float`s are inherently imprecise, so you may get a "stray" digit or two. For example, your example produces

```
[2 3 5 1 0 0 0 0 2 3]
```

with `2` and `3` at the end.

Comment: Tip: To avoid the mentioned inaccuracy of `float` introducing extraneous extra digits at the end, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) objects to represent fractional numbers instead of `float` and `double` primitives.

Comment: @BasilBourque Absolutely, `BigDecimal` would solve this problem. However, one needs to have `BigDecimal` to begin with. If you construct it from a `float` or `double`, the problem is back; if you start with a `String`, you can skip `BigDecimal` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `float` to `String` with 4 decimal places using `String.format` method, and then get each character to int array

```
float floatValue = 12.34567f;
String str = String.format("%.4f", floatValue);
// remove the minus, dot, or comma (used in some countries)
str = str.replaceAll("[-|.|,]", "");
int [] nums  = new int[str.length()];
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
  nums [i] = str.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://ideone.com/iOyYFQ)

As for the code last line, decimal value of **'0'** char (which is `48`) is subtracted from a decimal value of digit char, and the result is integer value of that digit (as specified in below table):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 flavored solution:

```
float number = -7.54f;
int[] digits = String.format("%.3f", number)
                     .chars()
                     .filter(Character::isDigit)
                     .limit(4L)
                     .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                     .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits)); //=> [7, 5, 4, 0]
```

Comment: I'd be glad if the downvoter could explain what's wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static method `Float.toString()` to convert your float to a String.

Then go through each char and use `Integer.parseInt()` to get back to an int.

```
public void printNumber(float number){
    String string = Float.toString(number);

    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        int j = Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(i));
        this.number = new Number(j);
        numbers.add(this.number);
        System.out.println("digit: " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   float number = 23.51f;
   String strNumber = String.valueOf(number).replaceAll("\\D", "");
   int[] arrNumber = new int[strNumber.length()];

   for (int pos = 0; pos < strNumber.length(); ++pos) {
        arrNumber[pos] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(strNumber.charAt(pos)));
        System.out.println(arrNumber[pos]);
    }
}
```